# In OpenGL ES, how do I load a texture that has transparent pixels?

Tags: opengl-es

And then have display correctly? An example would be having a round ball in a rectangle while being able to see another texture in the background.

edit: At the moment, when I load the texture the transparent pixels from the source image are displayed as black.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For iPhone and N95 this works:

If you are loading texture from raw data, set internal and source format to GL_RGBA.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
    GL_RGBA,
    textureWidth,
    textureHeight, 
    0, 
    GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pointerToPixels);
```

And when rendering, enable alpha blend:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: That works thanks! As a followup, how would I increase texture transparency after this?

Comment: Use color modulation.
glTexEnvx(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
Then set alpha component of the color to desired.
glColor4f(255, 255, 255, alpha);

Answer (score 13):

The answer provided by @Virne is correct, and I was able to use it for Android devices with a few small modifications.  The `myImage` object I used is a standard .png image with transparency.

I created the texture using this:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, myImage, 0);
```

And (like Virne), I enabled alpha blend when rendering:

```
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: If you are decoding the bitmap before setting it with texImage2d, don`t forget to specify that is a ARGB bitmap.:  
  BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap, opts);